# Trunc date oracle, Tuning SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Existe alguma forma de otimizar a query sql, onde é necessário truncar duas datas de uma coluna?

```
Select *
from work_table a
where trunc(a.datetime) = trunc(a.datetime);
```

Comment: Não entendi sua questão. A cláusula WHERE acima não será sempre verdadeira?

Comment: Não faz sentido essa query, pode explicar melhor seu problema?

Comment: Seria um problema de performance no caso , ao utilizar truncar duas datas na condição where, no caso o exemplo acima é apenas uma personificação da situação.
 -- > WHERE TRUNC(DATATIME) = TRUNC(DATATIME)

Comment: Analise o plano de execução e se a utilização de um function based index ajuda a melhorar a performance.